# Алгоритм для решения задачи о разбиении масива на 2 два одинаковых или максимально равных по суме

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

```js
function algoritm(arr) {
  try {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
      console.log('')
    }
    arr.sort((a, b) => b - a)
    let sum_arr1 = 0
    let sum_arr2 = 0;
    let arr_sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / 2
    let arr1 = []
    let arr2 = []

    arr.forEach(element => {
      if (sum_arr1 <= sum_arr2 || sum_arr2 >= arr_sum || sum_arr1) {
        arr1.push(element)
        sum_arr1 += element
      } else {
        arr2.push(element)
        sum_arr2 += element
      }
    });

    let response = {
      s1: arr1,
      s2: arr2
    }
    return JSON.stringify(response)
  } catch {
    console.log('Invalid data')
  }

}

console.log(algoritm([4, 5, 6, 7, 8]));
```

Comment: Не могу понять в чем проблема для [4,5,6,7,8] выдает [8,5,4] [7,6] а должно [6,5,4] [7,8]

Comment: добавь описание своего алгоритма. Очевидно - он не верен

Comment: код в вопросе не воспроизводит указанную ошибку

Answer (score 2):

Приведённый под пытается решить задачу жадным методом, однако в общем случае это не обеспечивает правильного решения.

Задача относится к классу subset sum (сумма подмножества) и может быть решена динамическим программированием. Переформулируя - требуется собрать подмножество с суммой `Sum/2` или максимально близкой.

Создаётся таблица длиной `Sum/2`. Нулевой элемент заполнен ненулевым значением, означающим, что сумму 0 собрать можно, остальные пока нулями.

Затем проходим по всем элементам `l` входного множества.

Для каждого проверяем ячейки таблицы в обратном порядке, чтобы исключить многократное использование элемента в наборе суммы.

Сумму `i` c использованием элемента `l` собрать можно, если существует возможная сумма `i-l`. Если сумма `i` встречается впервые, то записываем `l` в соответствующую ячейку на будущее. Тут же обновляем `best` - дистанцию, насколько набранная сумма близка к целевой.

По окончанию работы разматываем цепочку элементов, составляющих лучшую сумму. В ячейке `a[sum/2 - best]` ведь хранится слагаемое (`l`), с помощью которого получена эта сумма. В следующей ячейке, на которую указывает `l` (`a[i-l]` в основном алгоритме) - следующее слагаемое и т.д. Это получается одно подмножество, а не вошедшие в него элементы образуют второе.

Пример на Python: ([реализация на JS тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1208016/291659))

```
def halfsum(lst):
    halfs = sum(lst) // 2
    a = [0] * (halfs + 1)
    a[0] = -1
    best = halfs + 1

    for l in lst:
        for i in range(halfs, l-1, -1):
            if (a[i - l] !=0) and a[i] == 0:
                a[i] = l
                best = min(halfs - i, best)

    id = halfs - best
    b = []
    while (id > 0):
        b.append(a[id])
        id = id - a[id]
    return b

print(halfsum([3,11,29,53,13,7]))

>>[53, 3]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Можно пример на js пожалуйста

Comment: Добавь описание алгоритма словами.

Comment: @Grundy Добавил

Comment: @Maksym Zabolotnyi  Дал подробное описание.