# Алгоритм распределения элементов

Tags: алгоритм

Недавно был задан [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1433610/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC/1433617#1433617) вопрос.

---

Вот собственно его текст:

*Есть задача: У вас есть несколько камней известного веса. Напишите программу, которая распределит камни в две кучи так, что разность весов этих двух куч будет минимальной. Даже не представляю, как решить. Не подскажете, как это можно сделать? Мне не нужен код, нужен алгоритм. Спасибо!*

---

Я даже сам на него дал ответ. Но потом другой участник, написал, что этот алгоритм не верен.

*Ваш алгоритм `(8, 7, 5, 5, 5)` разделит на `(8, 5)`, `(7, 5, 5)`. А правильный ответ `(8, 7)`, `(5, 5, 5)`*

И действительно. Так вот, теперь я спрашиваю, как изменить алгоритм, что бы он работал и в этом случае?

---

Вот мой ответ:

*Постоянно добавляем в меньшую по весу кучу самый тяжелый камень.
Вот собственно и есть весь алгоритм.*

---

P.S. [Это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274797/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80) читал, там нет ответа на мой вопрос

P.P.S Задал этот вопрос, так [автор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/512409/novichok) [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1433610/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC/1433617#1433617)а выше не изменил вопрос.

P.P.P.S Пусть веса целые и до 100,000

Comment: Плохо искали, видимо: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1308964/291659

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, как я и писал, в [книге Кормена](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1794-2.html) эта задача разобрана, признана NP-полной, и вот описание точного алгоритма ее решения. Кто хочет — может взять книгу и почитать дальше, там приведен полиномиальный *приближенный* алгоритм.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Простого (*a la* жадного) решения не будет.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Надо же, я угадал. Подумал несколько минут и понял, что простого решения (с сортировками, деревом, частичными суммами и т.д.) не смогу придумать. Оказывается это уже давно доказано.